# @babel/polyfill: These dependencies were not found: core-js/fn/array/flat-map in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js

Tags: babeljs

Getting this error message from @babel/polyfill about some dependencies that were not found.

Why are these depeneendencies not installed along with @babel/polyfill

```
These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/fn/array/flat-map in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/promise/finally in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/string/pad-end in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/string/pad-start in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/string/trim-end in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/string/trim-start in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/fn/symbol/async-iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/noConflict.js
* core-js/library/fn/array/is-array in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/is-array.js
* core-js/library/fn/global in ./node_modules/@babel/polyfill/lib/index.js
* core-js/library/fn/parse-float in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/parse-float.js
* core-js/library/fn/parse-int in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/parse-int.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/fn/array/flat-map core-js/fn/promise/finally core-js/fn/string/pad-end core-js/fn/string/pad-start core-js/fn/string/trim-end core-js/fn/string/trim-start core-js/fn/symbol/async-iterator core-js/library/fn/array/is-array core-js/library/fn/global core-js/library/fn/parse-float core-js/library/fn/parse-int
ℹ ｢hot｣: webpack: Compiling Done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the lib (`core-js`) was accidentally required in a nodeJs environement (because of vscode auto-import new feature).

The project I'm working on contains 2 folders:

- `/lib` => compiled/babelised version for front-end use (should have `core-js` required)
- `/src` => not compiled for back-end nodeJs use (should **not** have `core-js` required)

I hope this will lead you to the right path :)